# Add query results to arrary PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am trying to add query results to an array. My while statement works but I am not getting anything in my array. Here is my code:

```
   $res=$pdo->query("select * from questions where category_id='$category' ORDER BY RAND()");
  $rows = $res->rowCount();
  if ($rows < 1){
    echo "There is no question in the database";
    exit();}

  $questionsArray = array();

  while ($item = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $questionsArray[] = $item;
    echo "There should be some info here<br>";
  }
```

Comment: you sure you don't have a typo wherever you're actually using the array? if you get the `There should be some ...` output, then the fetch IS working. where/how are you using `$questionsArray` later on?

Comment: try to put a `print_r($questionsArray)` after close the while

Comment: what ouput do you get when you use `var_dump($item)` in your `while()` loop?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider something like this, with thru PDO prepared statements.
Also, a while loop with a fetch is bad and slow and was good 15 years ago with MySQL.

Here is the proper way to do it.

```
define("SQLHOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("SQLUSER", "user");
define("SQLPASS", "password");
define("SQLSGBD", "database");

try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=' . SQLHOST . ';dbname=' . SQLSGBD . ';charset=UTF8', SQLUSER, SQLPASS);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$categories = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
$questionsArray = array();
$stmt = $con->prepare("select * from questions where category_id=? ORDER BY RAND()");
foreach ($categories as $key => $cat) {
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $cat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $obj = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (count($obj) !== 0) {
        foreach ($obj as $key2 => $item) {
            $questionsArray[] = [$cat => $item];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your ideas about while operator are... peculiar. Let alone that this post doesn't address the question at all.